# LISTAGG blowing up when view joined to another table

Tags: oracle, listagg

We have a view created which has a column using a select statement to generate a LISTAGG of values.

```
(select LISTAGG(distinct reporters_case_id, '; ') FROM cdss_live.CASE_REPORTER@SAPP_TRANSCT_DB CR WHERE cv.case_seq = cr.case_seq ) as ALL_REPORTER_CASE_IDs,
```

Querying this view works fine.

[image]

As soon as we join the view (VW_QRE_TEST) to another table.

```
select A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID,
        A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION,
        CASE WHEN (B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID IS NULL OR B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION IS NULL) THEN 'Select' else null end as Action
        from VW_TEST_QRE_STEP A LEFT JOIN T_PV_GLOBAL_INLINE_CASE_QC B
            ON A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID = B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID AND A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION = B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION
       WHERE
A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID = :P5_SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID;
```

It blows up:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-02063: preceding line from SAPP_TRANSCT_DB
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

Why would the listagg, which gets calculated in the view and works in isolation, suddenly blow up when joined to another table?  The listagg would be performed and isolated in the context of the view on its own, not in the context of a join taking place after the view is calculated?

Querying the view in isolation for the problem record, the listagg in isolation returns NULL, which is as expected - so there is nothing to listagg anyway.

Added a FIDDLE:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8bddf/15

UPDATE: The query runs fine if I remove the WHERE clause, which is odd...

```
select A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID,
        A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION,
        CASE WHEN (B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID IS NULL OR B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION IS NULL) THEN 'Select' else null end as Action
        from VW_TEST_QRE_STEP A LEFT JOIN T_PV_GLOBAL_INLINE_CASE_QC B
            ON A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID = B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID AND A.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION = B.SAPPHIRE_CASE_VERSION
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW` and `INSERT` statements necessary to replicate a minimal example of the problem (so that we can generate the error when we execute your query); and an `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your queries.

Comment: if the issue is the join somehow ending up linking to 1 million records, how will a minimal example help

Comment: Then you have to hope that the `EXPLAIN PLAN`s give us a clue because if you cannot replicate the problem then how do you expect us to answer the question beyond (educated) guesses? You may have a problem that the view is not being materialized and the aggregation is being pushed to an outer query (but that seems unlikely if the view is performing an aggregation) but we can't answer if you don't provide more information as we don't even have a complete DDL statement for the view or the underlying tables.

Comment: It looks like the ID you're looking for doesn't have an issue, but some other ID does - some `case_seq` has *lots* of `reporters_case_id` values. You could look at that remote table and see if that is the case, just by counting and finding the highest count. "listagg would be performed and isolated" isn't necessarily true; Oracle may combine the two view queries, and in doing so the predicate push may mean the listagg is evaluated for more rows than you expect - including for the actual problem ID. The execution plans may reveal if that is the case, as MTO said.

Comment: Added a fiddle, still confused about the behaviour of listagg within a view and then how that changes when the view is joined....

Comment: Your fiddle does not work.  I took the DDL and inserts/select and ran it on my local oracle and it works fine.  This is on 19c

Comment: The context is, the view in isolation works fine, returns null in the LISTAGG, when joined it blows up.  While I can create a fiddle to show what I am doing, as I don't know what is causing the issue I cant create records to cause a failure

Comment: @OldProgrammer fixed the fiddle

Comment: This is a [fixed fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c0424/2) and as @OldProgrammer states, it works. (The error was you using `#` instead of `--` for a comment).

Comment: it works great for me too, but for the odd record where it blows up, even though the listagg in isolation for that record returns null in the listagg. As I don't know whats causing the issue, I cant add records to simulate it, nor can I add millions of records in the fiddle

Comment: replace fiddle link in original question

Comment: @AlexPoole is there some kind of hint we can add to tell it not to do what its doing

Comment: I added more records on my db and just ran the sql from the view w/o the join and it blows up also.     You cannot return more than 4000 chars from listagg.

Comment: @smackenzie - quite possibly, but it depends what it's doing. A working fiddle (which isn't representative; e.g. no indexes, no DB link...) doesn't tell us that unfortunately. The actual execution plans from your real queries might.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am aware of LISTAGG limitations, but this record I am passing into the WHERE clause returns a NULL as the listagg result against the base view (when not joining).....in fact, I updated the question - when I don't include a WHERE clause the query runs without issue

Comment: @smackenzie - removing the `where` clause will change the execution plan again, and could affect the order things are evaluated. As could querying with a fixed value rather than a bind variable. (Your first query might even error if you use a bind variable for that.) You need to look at the execution plans; and hope those (and the differences between them) indicate where any why it's behaving differently.

Comment: @AlexPoole Explain plan, "SERIAL FOR REMOTE":  EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID='1682006097173' INTO PLAN_TABLE@! FOR SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT "A1"."REPORTERS_CASE_ID",'; '),"A1"."CASE_SEQ" FROM "CDSS_LIVE"."CASE_REPORTER" "A1" GROUP BY "A1"."CASE_SEQ"

Comment: Please show (via edit) an actual execution plan of the query collected via `dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor(...)` or `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(...)`. It will show if the view was [merged](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-4E431B5D-F61B-4F66-B86C-E9C8660E2FE7). You may try `/*+NO_MERGE(A)*/`hint (given that `VW_TEST_QRE_STEP` has this alias in your question) and test if it works. The reason of merge may be obtained from the plan itself (maybe optimizer expects low cardinality output) or from trace file for 10053 event.

Comment: I notice that a separate element of the explain plan for the listagg appears when I use a join, vs when I just query the view itself, related to the listagg

Comment: @AlexPoole /MERGE/ seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: @AlexPoole I noticed this was in the explain plan on the join scenario, not there when running the view on its own.  This looks like it is pushing down a general listagg, and something in the data (not related to the ID in the where clause) is blowing the listagg limit.    "SERIAL FOR REMOTE": EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID='1682006097173' INTO PLAN_TABLE@! FOR SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT "A1"."REPORTERS_CASE_ID",'; '),"A1"."CASE_SEQ" FROM "CDSS_LIVE"."CASE_REPORTER" "A1" GROUP BY "A1"."CASE_SEQ"